# Apply a cumulative function to a matrix by row with R

Tags: r, matrix, apply

I have an investment portfolio with an initial balance of say, $100,000 at the beginning of year one. I want to spend say, 4% of the previous year's end-of-year balance each year and then apply a portfolio growth rate to the remaining difference to obtain the EOY balance for the next year in the scenario. I have a matrix of market growth rates with a row for each scenario and a column for each year of that scenario.

For example, assume the first row/scenario has growth rates for 4 years(columns): 1.1, 0.9, 0.95 and 1.2.

My spending rate is 4% of the previous year's EOY balance (or the initial balance, for year 1). My initial balance is $100,000. At the end of the first year, my balance would be $100,000 - (.04 * 100,000) * 1.1, or $105,600.

At the end of the second year of this scenario, my balance would be $105,600 - (.04 * 105,600) * 0.9 or 108,518. I want to build a matrix of the EOY balances.

I can do this in R with loops, as follows. I am looking for a faster, simpler way to avoid loops. Any suggestions?

I have tried various apply functions with no success. Thanks!

```
rows <- 2
cols <- 4

# create 4 years (columns) of portfolio growth factors for each of two scenarios (rows)
marketReturns <- matrix(c(.9,1.1,.8,1.2,1.3,.95,1.3,.95),nrow=2,ncol=cols,byrow=TRUE)
bal <- matrix(0,rows,cols)

print("Market Growth Rates")
print(marketReturnsM)

initPortBal <- 10000   # initial portfolio balance

# create a matrix of annual end-of-year portfolio balances by subtracting a spending percentage
# from the previous year's EOY balance, then applying this year's portfolio growth factor
# gain or loss to the difference.
# For the first year, use the initial portfolio balance in place of the previous year's
# EOY balance.

spend = .04  # spend 4% of the previous year's EOY balance

for (i in (1:rows)){
  for (j in (1:cols)) {
    if (j > 1) {
      bal[i,j] <- (bal[i,j-1] - (spend * bal[i,j-1])) * marketReturns[i,j]
    } else {     # else use initial portfolio balance for last year's EOY balance
      bal[i,j] <- (initPortBal - (spend * initPortBal)) * marketReturns[i,j]
    }
  } # end j for loop
} # end i for loop

print("End of Year Balances")
print(bal)

[1] "Market Growth Rates"
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]  0.9 1.10  0.8 1.20
[2,]  1.3 0.95  1.3 0.95

[1] "End of Year Balances"
[,1]     [,2]      [,3]     [,4]
[1,]  8640  9123.84  7007.109  8072.19
[2,] 12480 11381.76 14204.436 12954.45
```

Comment: I didn't read this, but from the title, you might want to check out the `matrixStats` package. There are a number of cumulative functions available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An operation like `(x-(0.4*x))*0.9` can be simplified to `x*0.9*(1-0.4)`.  This means we can combine `spend` and `marketReturns` into one matrix `marketReturns*(1-spend)`, and then use `cumprod` and `apply` to find the cumulative product of this matrix over the columns.  All we need to do then is multiply that matrix by the initial balance.

```
t(apply(marketReturns*(1-spend),1,cumprod))*initPortBal
```

Comment: Moral of the story: don't let coding completely blind you to the math.

Answer (score 0):

You can formulate the progression from one year to the next as simple multiplication:

```
bal[i,j] <- bal[i,j-1] * (1 - spend) * marketReturns[i,j]
```

therefore you only need the cumulative product of your net returns:

```
netReturns <- (1 - spend) * marketReturns
cumNetReturns <- t(apply(netReturns, 1, cumprod))
bal <- initPortBal * cumNetReturns
```